# Bluetooth module resets because of LC filter

Tags: bluetooth, low-pass

I added MH-M18 Bluetooth audio module to my Z906 speakers. Speaker's console has only 3.3V, so I have to use boost converter.
For some reason, module outputs 200+Hz noise, no matter what connection status is.
After I added LC filter with cutoff 150Hz, module is in reset loop. LED on module blinks, but I can't find module with phone. Module consumes 20mA(by datasheet).
Scheme and component list are below. Sorry for sketch scheme, I don't have PC near right now. Thanks!

https://hr.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Taiyo-Yuden/EMK325ABJ476KMHP?qs=B6kkDfuK7%2FDcZxNrKjzaQw%3D%3D https://hr.mouser.com/ProductDetail/TDK/TPLC553030-592H?qs=lYGu3FyN48fhxsPwIV5J6g%3D%3D

[image: Scheme]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coil has a max DC resistance of 70 ohms - is not meant for power filtering.
It's a transponder coil for use such as tire pressure monitoring systems.

Comment: 5V/70ohm = 0.07A how it can't handle 20mA

Comment: But you don't have 5V over it, and don't want to have 5V over it at 20mA. Since the coil resistance is 70 ohms, 20mA*70 ohms = 1.4V voltage drop, so if 5V enters into the coil, and the module consumes 20mA, it will only have 3.6V of supply voltage. For a power supply filter, you want much less DC resistance, so the voltage drops less, and the module gets higher voltage.

Comment: So if I set voltage to 6.5V i should get 5V? I didn't look at datasheet - begginers mistake 

Comment: @SilvioCro maybe, but if the module consumes less current like it does in sleep or not connected modes, there is less voltage drop, and 6.5V can damage a 5V component. It's a wrong coil, it can't be used for power filtering, it is best to remove it.

Comment: Thanks, one more question - I can't wait for new coil, can I use RC filter with electrolytic caps(+-20% tol) instead?

Comment: I don't know what R and C values you are going to use so it will be hard to answer that. I also don't know what boost converter you are using so it is impossible to know how much capacitive load it allows. It is also difficult to know if the problem is that the input of boost converter causes the ripple to the 3.3V supply of the product and it couples to the amplifier, so the problem may not even be on the boost converter output.

Comment: RC with 1R and 2040uF solved the problem with noise. Thanks!